# How to pass the sitemap XML file to the Sitemap View Helper in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2, sitemap, viewhelper

I generated a `sitemap.xml` file and want to create a sitemap from it:

```
<?php
$this
    ->navigation()
    ->sitemap()
    ->setFormatOutput(true)
    ->setMaxDepth(2)
;
echo $this->navigation()->sitemap();
?>
```

How can I set the path to the file in the Sitemap view helper?

Comment: If you are manually creating it why would you want to do that? Or am I missing something...

Comment: I understod the function of the Sitemap view helper wrongly.Just overread the first line of the docu: "[The Sitemap helper is used for generating XML sitemap ...](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.navigation.view.helper.sitemap.html)" I thought it only displays an already generated sitemap. OK, thank you!